# Induced metric on product sub-manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $N_1(u)$ and $N_2(v)$ be a 1-dimensional curve, submanifold of $W$, and let $M(u,v)=N_1(u) \times N_2(v)$ be a 2-dimensional Riemannian product manifold, such that $M$ is also a submanifold of $W$.

If $W$ is not flat, could the metric induced on $M$ be non-flat?

EDIT after "Didier" messages.

Comment: A submanifold of $M$ would be zero dimensional, one dimensional or two dimensional. In the first two case, it is forced to be flat, while in the third one, it is an open subset of $M$ which is flat by your previous result.

Comment: @Didier - Thank you for your message. $M$ is 2-dimensional, it is a product-manifold of two curves and it is a 2-dimensional manifold. $M$ itself is flat because it is well known that a surface given by the Riemannian product of two curves, is flat, but what if it is a submanifold? So the induced metric will it necessarily be flat?

Comment: I answered this in my previous comment: a two dimensional submanifold is an open subset of $M$, hence is flat (as so $M$ is). A 0 dimensional submanifold is a point, and a 1 dimensional submanifold is a curve. These two last are always flat (there is no curvature because there is no tangent plane)

Comment: @Didier - Thank you very much again, one last clarification:
So the submanifold $M$, is flat because it is a two-dimensional submanifold given by the Riemannian product of two curves, Am I right? Because if $M$ was any surface (not product of two curves) then it could have a non-flat induced metric, Am I right?

Comment: $M$ is no submanifold (there is no ambiant manifold): it is defined as the Riemannian product of two curves. A Riemannian product $(N_1,g_1)\times (N_2,g_2)$ carries no curvature on tangent planes span$(X_1,X_2)$ if $X_i$ is tangent to $N_i$. Hence if $N_i$ are curves, the only tangent plane carry no curvature, and $M$ is flat.

Comment: but if we consider $X$ the tangent plane of $M$ given by $X_1 \oplus X_2$?

Comment: This is exactly what I was considering. Please read my comment carefully

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry. Last one..
But if $M$ were a 4-dimensional submanifold given by the Riemannian product of two 2-dimensional manifolds, then everything would be different, right? it would be a submanifold and I would have induced metrics.

Comment: I mean that the 2-dimensional manifolds are submanifold of $W$ and $M$ is their Riemannian product.. the same for the previous case with curves (the curves were submanifold of $W$).

Comment: If $M = (N_1\times N_2, g_1 \oplus g_2)$ is a product manifold of two surfaces, then $M$ may not be flat. For example, $S^2 \times S^2$ is non-negatively curved, with sectional curvature $+1$ for a plane tangent to $S^2$,  and $0$ for a mixed-plane (generated by two vectors in each copy of $S^2$).

Comment: Thank you very much, the thing I didn't understand is if I have two submanifolds ($N_1$ and $N_2$) of $W$, and if $M$ is given by the Riemannian product $N_1 \times N_2$, why can't $M$ be a submanifold of $W$? or this only if $N_1$ and $N_2$ are two curves?

Comment: $M$ would be a submanifold of $W\times W$, not $W$. The same way a product of two planar curves is a submanifold of $R^4 = R^2 \times R^2$, and not of the plane.

Comment: But for example, if $N_1$ and $N_2$ are curves of $W$, I can consider $W=\mathbb{R}^4$, so $M$ could be a submanifold of $W$.. or not?

Comment: If $W$ is a non-flat 4-manifold, where $N_1$ and $N_2$ are curves contained in $W$.
If I consider $M = N_1 \times N_2$ two-dimensional submanifold of $W$, then can $M$ have a non-flat induced metric?

Comment: It seems you're hoping to construct non-flat surfaces $M$ by taking Riemannian products of curves. If so, unfortunately you can't because a Riemannian product of curves is flat. There are certainly non-flat manifolds _diffeomorphic_ to a product of curves, such as tori in Euclidean three-space, but these are not _Riemannian_ products.

Comment: Thank you very much!